# Data Viewers showing + "0 rows" between all components in DFT

Tags: ssis

I need to debug my package so I've added a few data viewers between certain DFCs. There are 2 problems that I encounter :

1. The data viewers don't "pop up" when I run the package.
2. SSIS shows "0 rows" between all of my Data Flow Components (even for destination).

[image: 0 rows]

This would make sense if it was true and there was no data being transferred, but the thing is that my package **actually works** and there are ~3000 entries written to the database each time it's run.

I use VS2019 and the latest version (3.8) of SSIS Projects.

Comment: How do you have your Merge Join, Join Type configured? If you put a data viewer between the two feeds into the Merge Join, can you confirm the values for a Join Key exist in both sets and is the same case, same amount of trailing whitespace etc?

Comment: As a maintainer of many SSIS packages in my life, the length of your component friendly names indicates you don't have a package filled with the default names (Sort, Sort 1, etc) and that makes me very happy to see.

Comment: @billinkc I'm sorry I don't really understand your question. I can tell you that :It's an inner join and it works because this is the only destination of the DFT (and I'm only executing this specific DFT) and my tables receives a few thousands rows.

Comment: Inner Join is answer to the first question. If you put a Data Viewer on the two feeds coming into the Merge Join, can you see Column1 which is the match key from the left feed has a value of 12 and then the right feed has LegacyColumn1 and it too has a value of 12. If the data types aren't integers, then string matching comes into play.

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for complimenting my components names :) It's a big (really big) package that consists of INNER JOINing a ton of fields from a huge XML file. It's a nightmare, so I try my best to add a little peace in this monstruous chaos.

Comment: So you have N columns defined as Join Key(s). What are the data types in the data flow? Since XML, I presume they're all strings, yeah? What I'm wondering is whether you have things like "ABC" and "abc" trying to match. Yes they're the same characters but the matching rules will in this component will be a strict case sensitive match. Other things would be "ABC " would not match "ABC" because of the trailing space.

Comment: @billinkc I think the matching is going fine because, as I said, my table is fed with data. You're saying that incompatibility between JOINed fields types might prevent Data Viewers from showing ?

Comment: I know you state that you get data filled in production. The data viewer not showing any rows as well as indicating 0 rows is usually a sign that the data your working with is not matching. If you want to see what's working in prod, you can attach [Data Taps](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/12/13/ssis-data-taps/) to capture the two feeds into the component as well as what is coming out of it. Then compare the results to the Data Viewers you add to your local package (left and right input into the Merge Join) and then see whether the data viewer attached to the Merge Join Output remains 0

Comment: Ok, now I understand. A little correction : It's not that the Data Viewers show nothing, it's that they don't show at all (the window doesn't open up, is there something else to enable ?). I didn't know about Data Taps, however, "The use of SSIS data taps requires that the package being executed is deployed to the SSIS catalog" and, sadly, I don't have the necessary privileges to deploy packages.

Comment: Yeah, you usually have to coordinate with the SQL Server admins on the data tap front. The Data Viewer window doesn't pop unless there's a row that hits it. [Trivial Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGq2T.gif)

Comment: @LucasCharbonnier: Have you found a solution? I have exactly the same problem. Had worked in the past, but since I switched to VS 2017 and now to VS 2019, debugging no longer works correctly. Same effect as yours. Data Viewer is not displayed, Row Count is at 0 (even though data was processed correctly) and first and last component are green, the ones in between remain yellow rotating.

Comment: @Adrian Sorry, I don't use SSIS anymore and didn't further try to find a solution. I'm pretty sure SSIS is just broken